# Loading otf font as mathfont range using unicode-math

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, unicode-math

I'm trying to replace the letters in the math font so that it matches the main font. Curiously, this works for the italic version, yet not for bold and roman. Why is that?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Extension = .otf}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont = *-Italic, 
             BoldFont = *-Bold]{BemboStd}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathrm]{BemboStd}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{BemboStd-Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbf]{BemboStd-Bold}

\begin{document}

\noindent
abc \textit{abc} \textbf{abc} \\
$ \mathrm{abc} \ abc \ \mathbf{abc} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** Just in case it might be helpful to the next person, I'm now using

```
\setmathfont[range=\mathup/{latin,Latin}]{BemboStd}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin}]{BemboStd-Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup/{latin,Latin}]{BemboStd-Bold}
```

as to only substitute the normal letters, and leave all the greek and `\partial` glyphs alone.

Comment: Try `\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{BemboStd} \setmathfont[range=\mathit]{BemboStd-Italic} \setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{BemboStd-Bold}`

Comment: Thanks! This works. Although I don't know why.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Substituting `\mathrm` with `\mathup` and `\mathbf` with `\mathbfup` works:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{Extension = .otf}
\setmainfont[ItalicFont = *-Italic,
             BoldFont = *-Bold]{BemboStd}
\setmathfont{latinmodern-math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathup]{BemboStd}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit]{BemboStd-Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\mathbfup]{BemboStd-Bold}

\begin{document}

\noindent
abc \textit{abc} \textbf{abc} \\
$ \mathrm{abc} \ abc \ \mathbf{abc} $

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can find the reason why this works and your solution does not, in the following table (page 9 of `unicode-math` documentation)

[image]

As you can see `\mathrm` and `\mathbf` alphabets are not defined in Unicode.